# Mapping information from a SQLite database to QComboBox using the Model / View approach

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am in the situation described in https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq21-datawidgetmapper.html in the last section **'Mapping Information from a Database'**. The code is written in C++ and I cannot reproduce it in Python. I am not familiar with the concepts presented there anyway and this makes it harder for me. All I have done until now is to make the ComboBox show the information in the 'description' field of the 'addresstype' table but not the 'typeid' field of the 'person' table as it is supposed to do. Ideally I would like to solve this problem by creating a delegate for ComboBox according to the Model/View approach.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is recommended that you use the updated examples as some things may not remain. In this case the official example is [SQL Widget Mapper Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-sqlwidgetmapper-example.html).

In this example the [source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/sql/sqlwidgetmapper?h=5.15) is also indicated in C++ so the translation is trivial:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupModel()

        self.nameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tr("Na&me:"))
        self.nameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.addressLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tr("&Address:"))
        self.addressEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.typeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tr("&Type:"))
        self.typeComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.nextButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("&Next"))
        self.previousButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("&Previous"))

        self.nameLabel.setBuddy(self.nameEdit)
        self.addressLabel.setBuddy(self.addressEdit)
        self.typeLabel.setBuddy(self.typeComboBox)

        relModel = self.model.relationModel(self.typeIndex)
        self.typeComboBox.setModel(relModel)
        self.typeComboBox.setModelColumn(relModel.fieldIndex("description"))

        self.mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
        self.mapper.setItemDelegate(QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(self))
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.nameEdit, self.model.fieldIndex("name"))
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.addressEdit, self.model.fieldIndex("address"))
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.typeComboBox, self.typeIndex)

        self.previousButton.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toPrevious)
        self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toNext)
        self.mapper.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateButtons)

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.nameLabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.nameEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.previousButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.addressLabel, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.addressEdit, 1, 1, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.nextButton, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.typeLabel, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.typeComboBox, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("SQL Widget Mapper"))
        self.mapper.toFirst()

    def setupModel(self):
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName(":memory:")
        if not db.open():
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(
                None,
                self.tr("Cannot open database"),
                self.tr(
                    "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                    "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                    "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                    "to build it."
                ),
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
            )
            return

        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query.exec(
            "create table person (id int primary key, "
            "name varchar(20), address varchar(200), typeid int)"
        )
        query.exec(
            "insert into person values(1, 'Alice', "
            "'<qt>123 Main Street<br/>Market Town</qt>', 101)"
        )
        query.exec(
            "insert into person values(2, 'Bob', "
            "'<qt>PO Box 32<br/>Mail Handling Service"
            "<br/>Service City</qt>', 102)"
        )
        query.exec(
            "insert into person values(3, 'Carol', "
            "'<qt>The Lighthouse<br/>Remote Island</qt>', 103)"
        )
        query.exec(
            "insert into person values(4, 'Donald', "
            "'<qt>47338 Park Avenue<br/>Big City</qt>', 101)"
        )
        query.exec(
            "insert into person values(5, 'Emma', "
            "'<qt>Research Station<br/>Base Camp<br/>"
            "Big Mountain</qt>', 103)"
        )

        query.exec("create table addresstype (id int, description varchar(20))")
        query.exec("insert into addresstype values(101, 'Home')")
        query.exec("insert into addresstype values(102, 'Work')")
        query.exec("insert into addresstype values(103, 'Other')")

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("person")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)

        self.typeIndex = self.model.fieldIndex("typeid")

        self.model.setRelation(
            self.typeIndex, QtSql.QSqlRelation("addresstype", "id", "description")
        )
        self.model.select()

    def updateButtons(self, row):
        self.previousButton.setEnabled(row > 0)
        self.nextButton.setEnabled(row < self.model.rowCount() - 1)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! It works perfectly, now I can go on studying your answer and adopting it to my exact circumstances!